# Replacing values in one array with specific values of another array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two big numpy arrays or pandas dataframes, eg:

```
a=[[1, 10, 20, 30],[2, 50, 14, -10],[3, 11, 2, 0], ...] 

b=[[10, 40, 30, 1, 1, 2],[0, 11, -1, 32, 3, 2],[9, 2, 51, -2, 3, 2], ...]
```

I want to replace last two columns of the matrix b with values of a. I want to say when in the last two columns of a, we have 1, replace with the row in the a which contains 1 as the first column of a. this column is a counter from 1 to end. In fact at the end the columns of matrix b will be increased from 6 to 10.

So, the new b will be something like:

```
b=[[10, 40, 30, 1, 10, 20, 30, 50, 14, -10],[0, 11, -1, 32, 11, 2, 0, 50, 14, -10],[9, 2, 51, -2, 10, 20, 30, 11, 2, 0], ...]
```

I appreciate any solution to handle this request with the data either as numpy arrays or pandas.

Comment: Could you phrase your question better? I cannot understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: In fact, I want to replace the last two columns of a matrix (b), with values of another matrix (a) based on the values exisintg in b. For example when we see 1 in one of the two last columns, the algorithm should replace that 1 with the values exisinth in the first row of matrix a. These two columns of matrix b are representing counters and the attributes of these counters are stored in matrix a. Now, I want to replace the counter number with attribute of each number.

Comment: Problems of replacement look quite complicated for me at this moment. It would be much easier last two columns of `b` were indices of these 1 * 3 blocks to be replaced with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming first column of `a` is of the form `[1, 2, 3...]` it can be done with this one-liner:

```
np.c_[b[:,:-2], a[b[:,-2]-1, 1:], a[b[:,-1]-1, 1:]]
```

In fact, this is more convenient to replace `a` with `a[:, 1:]`, it can be simplified then like so:

`np.c_[b[:,:-2], a[b[:,-2]-1], a[b[:,-1]-1]]`

The last two columns of `b` were converted to indices of `a`. In case first column of `a` is different than `[1, 2, 3...]`, subtracting one is not enough and you need to think of different way how to map last two columns of `b` to indices with respect to `a`. I leave it out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.

1. If these are in pandas dataframes, you can join the 'a' dataframe to the 'b' dataframe twice, based on column b.5 = a0.1 and b.6 = a1.1. Then read off the columns you need (b.1-4, a0.2-4, a1.2-4. Something like:

   ```
   new1 = pd.merge(b, a, left_on='5', right_on='1')
   new2 = pd.merge(new1, a, left_on='6', right_on='1')
   ```

Then drop columns 5 and 6

2. otherwise would suggest turning 'a' to a different structure, a list of tuples or a dictionary. Your index is embedded as the first value, so if you went the dictionary rout you would try to get {1:[10, 20, 30], 2:[50, 14, -10], 3:[11, 2, 0] ... } and that makes the lookup easier.

   ```
   newlist = []
   for x in b:
       q = x[:4]
       q.extend(a[x[4]])
       q.extend(a[x[5]])
       newlist.append(q)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I really appreciate it. I tried the fisrt solution but but was giving me only an empty pandas datadfarme with 17 columns.

Comment: I'd need to see the code. I don't know your column names, so you need to put them in the left_on and right_on fields.